# MSBuild Extensions Pack, gacutil, Win32_Process, Life, the Universe and Everything

Tags: .net, msbuild, wmi, gac, msbuildextensionpack

I've been trying to get the MSBuild Extensions Pack GAC utility working but keep coming up against the *Remote AddAssembly returned non-zero returnValue: 9* error that usually points to gacutil.exe not being in the path.  I've added the location of gacutil to the system PATH and confirmed that it works by running *gacutil.exe /l* from the run dialog, but this hasn't helped.

To check if there was a problem with WMI on the machine, I used PowerShell to try to invoke gacutil using Win32_Process and this failed in the same way, but when I set the commandline to be the actual path that worked.

Might I need to reboot the server so WMI reads in the new PATH variable, or is something odder happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you need to reboot after changing PATH variable

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  I didn't think it was needed since a new shell should pick up any changes, but I guess remoting is different.